# JQuery Sortable that scrolls

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two jquery sortables that connect to each other (code below).

```
$('#da_favourites_sortable').sortable({
    connectWith:  '#da_available_sortable',
    handle:   'img.da_icon_handle',
    revert:  true
});

$('#da_available_sortable').sortable({
    connectWith:  '#da_favourites_sortable',
    handle:   'img.da_icon_handle',
    revert:  true
});
```

What I would like to do is make one of them a scrolling panel (#da_available_sortable) so that I can have multiple "pages" of sortable element that I can move between the panels.

I can't seem to find away to do this that doesn't cause me to have to split the "available" panel into multiple li's. This is obviously not going to work when I want to drag elements into the "multiple page" sortable as each li would end up having to be a separate sortable.

I would like the #da_available_sortable sortable to show 10 elements at a time as two rows of five.

Has anybody done this before that can show me the way forward?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. Are you looking for something like this?

http://jsbin.com/ekinog/8

In head:

```
<style>
  #wrapper {
    border:solid 1px #cacaca;
    height:5em;
    overflow-y:scroll;
  }
 </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){    

$('#da_favourites_sortable').sortable({
    connectWith:  '#da_available_sortable',
    revert:  true
});

$('#da_available_sortable').sortable({
    connectWith:  '#da_favourites_sortable',
    revert:  true
});   


});
</script>
```

In body:

```
<ul id="da_favourites_sortable">
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>        
  </ul>     

  <div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="da_available_sortable">
     <li>Dolor</li>
     <li>Sit</li>
     <li>Amet</li>
     <li>Consectetur</li>
     <li>Adipiscing</li>
     <li>Elit</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```